# HashSet loses the old element when adding a new one

Tags: java, arrays, hash, hashset

It is necessary for a HashSet to be defined in one class, and for me to access this HashSet from other classes and add data to it. However, it doesn't go very easily, because every time it's as if the HashSet is reset and when I add a new element, the old one is gone.

Output:

> []
>
> [[sdadsa, fafafsa, ghfhgf, kjhkjh]]
>
> [[], [sdadsa, fafafsa, ghfhgf, kjhkjh]]

First class:

```
public class listaKlasa {
    
        protected static Set<ArrayList<String>> unikatna = new HashSet<ArrayList<String>>();
    
        public static void setUnikatna(ArrayList<String> ista) {
            unikatna.add(ista);
        }
    
        public static Set<ArrayList<String>> getUnikatna() {
            return unikatna;
        }
    }
```

Secund class:

```
public class novitest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println(listaKlasa.getUnikatna());
        ArrayList<String> li = new ArrayList<>();
        li.add("sdadsa");
        li.add("fafafsa");

        ArrayList<String> la = new ArrayList<>();
        li.add("ghfhgf");
        li.add("kjhkjh");

        listaKlasa.setUnikatna(li);

        System.out.println(listaKlasa.getUnikatna());
        listaKlasa.setUnikatna(la);
        System.out.println(listaKlasa.getUnikatna());
    }
}
```

Comment: I can see no unexpected behavior in the output you provide. You are adding 1 empty list and 1 list with 4 elements to your set, and that is what it prints out. Maybe you confused yourself because you gave your ArrayList really bad variable names and therefor seem to have mixed up `la` and `li` (You are only adding to `li`, `la` stays empty)

Comment: This probably goes wrong because somewhere you are modifying the `ArrayList` while it's stored in the `HashSet`. That will make the `ArrayList`'s hash code change while its in the set, which will confuse the set.

Comment: By the way, you should follow the Java Naming Conventions: variable names and method names are written in camelCase, and class names in PascalCase.

Comment: I agree with OH GOD SPIDERS here, the output in its current form is what I would expect the output to be. `li` contains 4 elements, and `la` contains 0 elements when you add them to the `Set`.

Answer (score 0):

The mistake is adding elements, instead of adding 2: 2, you added everything to one list.

First class:

```
public class listaKlasa {
    
        protected static Set<ArrayList<String>> unikatna = new HashSet<ArrayList<String>>();
    
        public static void setUnikatna(ArrayList<String> ista) {
            unikatna.add(ista);
        }
    
        public static Set<ArrayList<String>> getUnikatna() {
            return unikatna;
        }
    }
```

Secund class:

```
   public class novitest {
    
        public static void main(String[] args) {
    
            System.out.println(listaKlasa.getUnikatna());
            ArrayList<String> li = new ArrayList<>();
            li.add("sdadsa");
            li.add("fafafsa");
    
            ArrayList<String> la = new ArrayList<>();
            la.add("ghfhgf");
            la.add("kjhkjh");
    
            listaKlasa.setUnikatna(li);
    
            System.out.println(listaKlasa.getUnikatna());
            listaKlasa.setUnikatna(la);
            System.out.println(listaKlasa.getUnikatna());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
System.out.println(listaKlasa.getUnikatna());
        ArrayList<String> li = new ArrayList<>();
        li.add("sdadsa");
        li.add("fafafsa");

        ArrayList<String> la = new ArrayList<>();
        la.add("ghfhgf");
        la.add("kjhkjh");
```